Finitely ramified global Galois character is trivial on a subgroup of finite index in \mathcal{O}_K^*
In Lawrence-Venkatesh, they state before lemma 2.8 that if a continuous $\eta:{\rm Gal}(\bar{K}/K)\to\mathbb{Q}_p^*$ is finitely ramified, where $K$ is a number field, then the induced homomorphism $\eta_p:(K\otimes\mathbb{Q}_p)^*\to\mathbb{Q}_p^*$ is trivial on a finite-index subgroup of $\mathcal{O}_K^*$. (Maybe there is a further requirement that $\eta_p$ is locally algebraic).
I don't understand why this holds. I know that the finitely-ramified condition means the induced Hecke character is trivial on $\mathcal{O}_{K_v}^*$ for almost all $v$. Then $\eta_p$ sends $a\in\mathcal{O}_K^*$ to the product $\prod_{v}\eta_v(a)$ for all $v|p$ at which $\eta$ is ramified. But why the kernel of this map is of finite index in $\mathcal{O}_K^*$.
